# 304 not modified when using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, tabs

I am encountering a 304 not modified when switching between tabs. Jquery ajax call is sent underlying. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: need more information. Paste the main code

Comment: @liunian sorry, i has nothing to do with ajax call, but just the html page of the tab is cached some how.

Comment: can you paste some code? so we can see what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you use Get to finish with `ajax`. You may try `$.post` or add a random parameter like this:

```
$.get(url,{randomKey:Math.random()+Date.parse(Date()},callback)
```

Comment: This is not the reason for the issue. But the above sounds useful.